# change .css class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this slidetoggle and I want the style of the open toggle to be different then the closed ones.

By default all the `faqtopics1` are set to  `border-radius: 5px; background-color: #f2ecec;` when the div `faqtext` associated opens.

When the toggle opens, I want the style of `faqtopics1` to be set to the "OnClick Style"

```
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
background-color: #dedcdc;
```

I found out about the .css() Method and could somehow make something up (line 2 and 3):

```
   $(".faqtopics1").click(function(event) {
        $("div.faqtopics1").css({"border-radius":"5px", "background-color":"#f2ecec"});
        $(this).css({"border-radius":"5px 5px 0 0", "background-color":"#dedcdc"});
        $("div.faqtext").stop(true).slideUp(400);
        $(this).next("div.faqtext").stop(true).slideToggle();
    });
```

But it's not a total success as even when I re-click on a toggle to close it, the OnClick style remains. Is there a better way to make what I want ?

Also I want to apply the same principal even if I click on faqtopics2, faqtopics3 or faqtopics4 div. (cf the jsfiddle).

You can find my codes (css + query) on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UwGs7/4/)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something much easier:

Define your two states in CSS:

```
faqtopics1 {
  border-radius: 5px; 
  background-color: #f2ecec;
}

.onclickstyle {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: #dedcdc;
}
```

Then in JS you just have to toogle the class:

```
$("div.faqtopics1").toggleClass("onclickstyle");
```

This means you have a clear separation between the exact style (in the css), and the dynamic toogle (in the javascript).

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$('faqtopics1').attr('class','newClassName');
```

Comment: That will remove the old class and add a new one. So just make sure you have the classes defined in your css file.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to use addClass.

```
$this.addClass('active');
```

Then in your css

```
.faqtopics.active{border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; background-color:#dedcdc;}
```

You can give all of your "FAQ topics" a shared class `.faqtopics` and then unique id's `#faqtopic1 #faqtopic2` if you need to style them a bit differently.